# How to run ffmpeg command from the client side?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, live-streaming

I am trying to make an online examination portal. When students start the exam, their webcam will start automatically and record the stream live and store in the server. Invigilators will either watch the students live or they can watch the saved live streams later.

After many research on various technologies I came across [this](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets) link. It uses Node JS with websockets and ffmpeg. I ran the ffmpeg command and it streamed the live video successfully.

But the problem is, in order to live stream, the students have to have ffmpeg installed in their system and they should run the command directly from the terminal. So how can I change this? The students will live stream from their browser, because this is a web portal. If we put this command in a PHP script, then the command will run at the server side. But client side command should run in this case. How can I run command from client side?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Why not just use YouTube Live or similar?

Comment: Its an online examination portal. I think for YouTube Live the people who will live stream should have Youtube channel and the live video will be broadcasted to everyone. This is not my requirement for the site.